# I need the name of an older movie about a portal to another world. (Not The Gate)

Tags: story-identification, movie

I was very young so I would say a mid to late 90's movie. I remember something about a portal to another world in a kids' backyard. Several kids are involved. Something about a fort or tree house maybe. Something about a creature with a long tongue grabbing some kid by the leg and there was a magic crystal. May have also been some flying creatures...(may have come out of a TV?) There is a good creature I think and the kids help free him from capture and then at the end I believe the tongue creature is taken away by some guardian creatures or people and they go down into the ground and the portal is closed.

At first I thought it was 1987's *The Gate* or the sequel that came a few years later, but after having watched both of them I can safely say no, not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Hi there! :) that's a nicebeginning. Maybe you could add some other details? Like what language was spoken? Or take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question), maybe it could trigger some memories :)